# Query execution time increases after adding order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I use following query to fetch around data from 15 columns from **four tables**

```
SELECT company_table.some_values,
        log_table.somevalues,
        employee_table.somevalues,
        manager_table.somevalues

FROM company_table

JOIN log_table 
ON company_table.id = log_table.id 
AND company_table.department = log_table.dept 

JOIN employee_table 
ON employee_table.id = log_table.id 
AND employee_table.year = log_table.joining 
AND employee_table.department = log_table.dept 

JOIN manager_table 
ON manager_table.id = log_table.id 
AND manager_table.year = log_table.joining 
AND manager_table.department = log_table.dept 

ORDER BY log_table.id DESC
```

Output is correct but it takes more time to execute. But if I remove order by then execution time is reduced by considerable amount. I tried with order by ascending still it takes more time

Comment: It's hardly surprising that it increases the compilation time.  Once all the results are fetched from memory into the cursor (the query result) then MySQL has to perform a sort algorithm on that data-set thus increasing your query time. How many rows are you fetching, do you need all that data in one go, could you paginate the results? This may reduce your overhead

Comment: I used indexing but it is still taking much time to fetch records.. about 2 seconds for 50k records and 0.0034 seconds without order by

Comment: Alex I am using pagination of 100 records but still if I remove order by it shows result very quick than with order by. 100 is very less count to take time

Comment: Did you put index on log_table.id ?

Comment: I am not much familiar with indexing. But I have created index in each above table with using columns that are used in join. eg index in log_table is combination of id,dept and joining columns. Is it right way of indexing or I am doing it wrong

Comment: Additional indexes should never slow down a query. That would mean that the optimizer does a bad job (by picking a less adequate index). I don't say that this can *never* happen, but it's quite unlikely.

Comment: are you doing SELECT * for those 15 columns by any chance? If so, take it out and take what you need

Comment: No I specified only required columns in select

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your tables are not designed correctly.

I think you have recurring values in your `log_table.id` column, because I suspect it doesnt truly have a unique index for a primary key, or a correct primary key, since its `id` column doubles up as the company id also. This is why I have this notion:

```
ON company_table.id = log_table.id 
AND company_table.department = log_table.dept
```

If either or both of these columns are/make up your primary key, which I suspect they are not, they are not the correct choice.

So it will do a good job of retrieving things in the order they are found, but a little extra work has to be done when ordering because you can potentially have colliding values, that and you have to `join` on 2 columns.

If what above is true, you can try this. **Backup before trying, or try on dev.**

Try adding a new column for a primary key and ordering on that:

```
ALTER TABLE log_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE log_table ADD pk_column INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

then `ORDER BY pk_column` DESC.

If you have specified another column in `log_table` as your primary key, `order by` on that instead.